# My Application runs perfectly on AVD but when on the real device it does not send the data to my wampserver

Tags: android, mysql, inputstream, wampserver

I am working on  food ordering application as my project at school, and most of it is running smooth. The code that I will upload bellow works perfectly on the AVD and I can visualize it at my wampserver, however when using the same code on a real device it is not able to send the data. I changed the IP address to my local IP but it gives me an error pointing to the line
 InputStream IS = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
and 
public class BackgroundTask extends AsyncTask

I will upload the codes in here in the hope that someone can help me.

Thanks in advance

This is my checkout basket where I send the data to the background task

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.checkout_basket_layout);
    total_txt=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.total_txt);
    total=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.total);
    paypal=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.paypal_btn);
    paypal.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "FUNCTION DISABLED", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });

    cancel = (Button)findViewById(R.id.cancel_order);
    basket_menu=(Button)findViewById(R.id.menu_basket);
    promocode=(Button)findViewById(R.id.promocode_btn);
    enter_code=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.enter_code);

   //List View
    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.checkout_list);
    checkoutAdapter = new CheckoutAdapter(getApplicationContext(),R.layout.checkout_row_layout);
    checkoutAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    listView.setAdapter(checkoutAdapter);
    databaseOperations = new DatabaseOperations(getApplicationContext());
    sqLiteDatabase = databaseOperations.getReadableDatabase();
    cursor = databaseOperations.getInformation(sqLiteDatabase);
    if (cursor.moveToFirst())
    {
        do{
            String order, combo, juice;
            String pricetxt;
            Long price;


            order = cursor.getString(0);
            combo = cursor.getString(1);
            juice=cursor.getString(2);
            price= cursor.getLong(3);
            BigDecimal price2= new BigDecimal(price);
            BigDecimal price1;
            BigDecimal cents = new BigDecimal(100);
            price1= price2.divide(cents);
            price1.setScale(2, BigDecimal.ROUND_CEILING);
            pricetxt= price1.toString();

            CheckoutDataProvider dataProvider = new CheckoutDataProvider(order, combo, pricetxt, juice);
            checkoutAdapter.add(dataProvider);
        }
        while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }

    cur = databaseOperations.getTotal(sqLiteDatabase);

    if(cur.moveToFirst())
    {
        do
        {
            Long total1;
            String total_bill;
            total1=cur.getLong(0);
            BigDecimal total2= new BigDecimal(total1);
            BigDecimal total3;
            BigDecimal cents = new BigDecimal(100);
            total3= total2.divide(cents);
            total3.setScale(2, BigDecimal.ROUND_CEILING);
            total_bill=total3.toString();

            total.setText(total_bill);
        }

        while (cur.moveToNext());

    }


}
public void back_menu (View view)
{

    Intent intent=new Intent(CheckoutBasket.this,MainActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}

public void cancel_order (View view)
{

    SQLiteDatabase sdb = databaseOperations.getWritableDatabase();
    sdb.delete(OrderData.OrderInfo.TABLE_NAME, null, null);
    sdb.execSQL("delete from " + OrderData.OrderInfo.TABLE_NAME);
    sdb.close();
    checkoutAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    Intent intent=new Intent(CheckoutBasket.this,MainActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);



}

public void use_promocode (View view)
{
    databaseOperations = new DatabaseOperations(getApplicationContext());
    sqLiteDatabase = databaseOperations.getReadableDatabase();
    cursor = databaseOperations.getInformation(sqLiteDatabase);
    if (cursor.moveToFirst())
    {
        do{
            String order, combo, juice;
            String pricetxt;
            Long price;


            order = cursor.getString(0);
            combo = cursor.getString(1);
            juice=cursor.getString(2);
            price= cursor.getLong(3);
            BigDecimal price2= new BigDecimal(price);
            BigDecimal price1;
            BigDecimal cents = new BigDecimal(100);
            price1= price2.divide(cents);
            price1.setScale(2, BigDecimal.ROUND_CEILING);
            pricetxt= price1.toString();

            String method = "register";
            BackgroundTask backgroundTask=new BackgroundTask(this);
            backgroundTask.execute(method,order,combo,juice,pricetxt);


        }
        while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }



}
```

The next code is my background task

```
public class BackgroundTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
Context ctx;

BackgroundTask(Context ctx)
{
    this.ctx=ctx;
}

@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    super.onPreExecute();

}

@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
    String reg_url = "http://39.109.153.156/order/register.php";
    String method = params [0];


    if (method.equals("register"))
    {
        String order = params[1];
        String combo =params[2];
        String juice = params[3];
        String pricetxt = params [4];

        try {
            URL url = new URL(reg_url);
            HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
            httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
            Log.d("URLConnection", "Connection created");
            OutputStream OS = httpURLConnection.getOutputStream();
            BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(OS, "UTF-8"));
       String data = URLEncoder.encode("main","UTF-8") +"="+URLEncoder.encode(order,"UTF-8")+"&"+
               URLEncoder.encode("combo","UTF-8") +"="+URLEncoder.encode(combo,"UTF-8")+"&"+
               URLEncoder.encode("juice","UTF-8") +"="+URLEncoder.encode(juice,"UTF-8")+"&"+
               URLEncoder.encode("pricetxt","UTF-8") +"="+URLEncoder.encode(pricetxt,"UTF-8");
            bufferedWriter.write(data);
            bufferedWriter.flush();
            bufferedWriter.close();
            Log.d("BufferedWriter", "Writer created");
            OS.close();
            InputStream IS = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
            IS.close();
            return "Transaction Successful";
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }


    return null;
}

@Override
protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
    super.onProgressUpdate(values);
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result)
{
    Toast.makeText(ctx, result, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

}

If I am no using the right tools to do that, can somebody please help me to point a way which I can follow?

Thanks to all

Comment: It is possible that the AVD and real device have a different visibility on the local URL. Is the real device connected to the same network? The AVD may have access to the LAN that the local web server and local device are connected to. The web server may not be visible to the real device.

Comment: try `http://39.109.153.156/order/` url in mobile web browser first and make sure mobile and laptop are in same network

Comment: They are connected to the same network I will try changing ip address,

Answer (score 0):

For it to work, you need to have your computer and device to use the same network (e.g the same wi-fi). If they are using the same network (wi-fi) then use Wireless LAN ipv4 address as your base url. e.g http://192.168.44.77/project